# How can I back fill null values in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to perform a null backfill, similar to Panda's dataframe bfill, in BigQuery. Reading the docs, the `last_value` function seems to be a good choice. However, this leaves some `null` spots until it finds the first value (quite reasonable, given the name of the function). How can I backfill those `null`? Or I just have to drop them?

This is a sample query:

```
select table_path.*, last_value(sn_6 ignore nulls) over (order by time)
from (select 1 as time, null as sn_6 union all
      select 2, 1 union all
      select 3, null union all
      select 4, null union all
      select 5, null union all
      select 6, 0 union all
      select 7, null union all
      select 8, null
     ) table_path;
```

Actual output:

```
time    sn_6    f0_
1       null   null
2         1     1
3       null    1
4       null    1
5       null    1
6         0     0
7       null    0
8       null    0
```

Desired output:

```
time    sn_6    f0_
1       null    1 <---Back fill all the gaps!
2         1     1
3       null    1
4       null    1
5       null    1
6         0     0
7       null    0
8       null    0
```

The real data has a `timestamp` column followed by 6 `float` columns and there are null values everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the intention is to make the missing "backfill" to be a "forward-fill", you can use `first_value` function to look forward to locate the first non-null value, as:

```sql
select table_path.*, 
coalesce(
  last_value(sn_6 ignore nulls) over (order by time),
  first_value(sn_6 ignore nulls) over (order by time RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  )
from (select 1 as time, null as sn_6 union all
      select 2, 1 union all
      select 3, null union all
      select 4, null union all
      select 5, null union all
      select 6, 0 union all
      select 7, null union all
      select 8, null
     ) table_path;
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much :). I feel that I am lacking a lot of bigquery sql dialect. Is there any course, tutorial or something you could recommend me?

Comment: Google Cloud has official course on Coursera https://www.coursera.org/professional-certificates/gcp-data-engineering and bunch of other courses